# Configuring uwsgi to output json encoded logs on separate lines

Tags: uwsgi

I would like uwsgi to output log messages in json on separate lines. I have tried adding the following to the `uwsgi.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
log-encoder = json {"unix":${unix}, "msg":"${msg}"}
```

but then all the logs get smushed together on one line:

```
$ uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
{"unix":1534303044, "msg":"nodename: RC00W00K3HTD6"}{"unix":1534303044, "msg":"machine: x86_64"}{"unix":1534303044, "msg":"clock source: unix"}{"unix":1534303044, "msg":"pcre jit disabled"}{"unix":1534303044, "msg":"detected number of CPU cores: 8"}
```

I can make it output on separate lines if I pass `--log-encoder` as a command line argument to `uwsgi`:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --log-encoder=$'json {"unix":${unix}, "msg":"${msg}"}\n'
```

However I would prefer all the configuration lives in the one `.ini` file. I tried adding `\n` to the end of the line like so:

```
[uwsgi]
log-encoder = json {"unix":${unix}, "msg":"${msg}"}\n
```

But that just causes `\n` to be printed between messages.

I am running uwsgi v2.0.17.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by actually reading [the docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/LogEncoders.html):

> Encoders can be added by plugins, and can be enabled in chain (the output of an encoder will be the input of the following one and so on).

There is a built-in newline encoder so we can combine that with the json encoder like so:

```
[uwsgi]
log-encoder = json {"unix":${unix}, "msg":"${msg}"}
log-encoder = nl
```

Comment: If I use a file specific to uwsgi it works, however if I share it with Pyramid it doesn't.